# NullPointer when trying to return Object from SQLite database

Tags: sqlite, nullpointerexception, cursor

I have a simple android app that takes in 2 player names, then launches the GameActivity activity.

The game activity is a simple tic tac toe game. When the 2 players finish the game, it should increment the winners 'wins' in the db by 1, and the same with 'losses' for the loser.

Within my end game function, which is called when a player gets 3 X's or Os in a line, I am writing

```
        Player player1;
        player1 = db.returnPlayerByName(player_one);
        db.insertWinnerScore(player1);
```

db in an instance of the ScoreDB class (SQLite database). Within that class, I have a 'returnPlayerByName' method which takes in a user's name (string) and a 'getPlayerFromCursor' method which takes in the cursor from the returnPlayerByName method.

```
    public Player returnPlayerByName(String name){
    String where = PLAYER_NAME + "=?";
    String[] whereArgs = {name};

    this.openReadableDB();
    try {
        Cursor cursor = db.query(PLAYER_TABLE, null, where, whereArgs, null, null, null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        Player player = getPlayerFromCursor(cursor);
        if (cursor != null){
            cursor.close();
        }

        this.closeDB();
        return player;
    } catch (Exception e){
        Log.d("PlayerApp", "Exception " + e);
        return null;
    }

}

private static Player getPlayerFromCursor(Cursor cursor) {
    if (cursor == null || cursor.getCount() == 0){
        return null;
    }
    else {
        try {
            Player player = new Player(
                    cursor.getInt(PLAYER_ID_COL),
                    cursor.getString(PLAYER_NAME_COL),
                    cursor.getInt(WINS_COL),
                    cursor.getInt(LOSSES_COL),
                    cursor.getInt(TIES_COL));
            return player;
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            Log.d("PlayerApp", "Exception " + e);
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

My error is as follows

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'com.mad.playerappcos.Player com.mad.playerappcos.ScoreDB.returnPlayerByName(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
```

I understand the error of course, I just don't understand why the method is catching an exception. Probably something small but I have been looking at it for a few hours now with no solution.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
package com.mad.playerappcos;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory;
import android.util.Log;

import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
 * Created by oshau on 10/02/2018.
 */

public class ScoreDB {

    public static final String DB_NAME = "score.db";
    public static final int DB_VERSION = 1;

    public static final String PLAYER_TABLE = "player";

    public static final String PLAYER_ID = "_id";
    public static final int PLAYER_ID_COL = 0;

    public static final String PLAYER_NAME = "player_name";
    public static final int PLAYER_NAME_COL = 1;

    public static final String WINS = "wins";
    public static final int WINS_COL = 2;

    public static final String LOSSES = "losses";
    public static final int LOSSES_COL = 3;

    public static final String TIES = "ties";
    public static final int TIES_COL = 4;

    public static final String DROP_PLAYER_TABLE =
            "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + PLAYER_TABLE;

    public static final String CREATE_PLAYER_TABLE =
            "CREATE TABLE " + PLAYER_TABLE + " (" +
            PLAYER_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
            PLAYER_NAME + " TEXT UNIQUE, " +
            WINS + " INT, " +
            LOSSES + " INT, " +
            TIES + " INT)";


    private static class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

        public DBHelper(Context context, String name,
                        CursorFactory factory, int version) {
            super(context, name, factory, version);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
            // create tables
            db.execSQL(CREATE_PLAYER_TABLE);
        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

        }

    }
    private SQLiteDatabase db;
    private DBHelper dbHelper;

    public ScoreDB(Context context){
        dbHelper = new DBHelper(context, DB_NAME, null, DB_VERSION);
    }

    private void openReadableDB() {
        db = dbHelper.getReadableDatabase();
    }

    private void openWriteableDB() {
        db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    }

    private void closeDB() {
        if (db != null)
            db.close();
    }

    public long insertPlayer(Player player){
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put(PLAYER_NAME, player.getName());
        cv.put(WINS, player.getWins());
        cv.put(LOSSES, player.getLosses());
        cv.put(TIES, player.getTies());

        this.openWriteableDB();
        long rowID = db.insert(PLAYER_TABLE, null, cv);

        return rowID;
    }

    public ArrayList<Player> getPlayers() {
        ArrayList<Player> players = new ArrayList<Player>();
        openReadableDB();
        Cursor cursor = db.query(PLAYER_TABLE,
                null, null, null, null, null, null);
        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
            Player player = new Player();
            player.setPlayerID(cursor.getInt(PLAYER_ID_COL));
            player.setName(cursor.getString(PLAYER_NAME_COL));
            player.setWins(cursor.getInt(WINS_COL));
            player.setLosses(cursor.getInt(LOSSES_COL));
            player.setTies(cursor.getInt(TIES_COL));

            players.add(player);
        }
        cursor.close();
        closeDB();
        return players;
    }
    public ArrayList<String> getPlayerNames() {
        ArrayList<String> players = new ArrayList<String>();
        openReadableDB();
        Cursor cursor = db.query(PLAYER_TABLE,
                null, null, null, null, null, null);
        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
            Player player = new Player();
            player.setPlayerID(cursor.getInt(PLAYER_ID_COL));
            player.setName(cursor.getString(PLAYER_NAME_COL));
            player.setWins(cursor.getInt(WINS_COL));
            player.setLosses(cursor.getInt(LOSSES_COL));
            player.setTies(cursor.getInt(TIES_COL));

            players.add(player.getName());
        }
        cursor.close();
        closeDB();
        return players;
    }

    public void insertWinnerScore(Player player){

        String where = PLAYER_NAME + "= ?";
        String[] whereArgs = {player.getName()};
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put(WINS, getCurrentWins(player) + 1);

        this.openWriteableDB();
        db.update(PLAYER_TABLE, cv, where, whereArgs);

    }

    public void insertLoserScore(Player player){

        String where = PLAYER_NAME + "= ?";
        String[] whereArgs = {player.getName()};
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put(WINS, getCurrentLosses(player) + 1);

        this.openWriteableDB();
        db.update(PLAYER_TABLE, cv, where, whereArgs);

    }

    public void insertTieScore(Player player){

        String where = PLAYER_NAME + "= ?";
        String[] whereArgs = {player.getName()};
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put(WINS, getCurrentTies(player) + 1);

        this.openWriteableDB();
        db.update(PLAYER_TABLE, cv, where, whereArgs);

    }


    public Player returnPlayerByName(String name){
        String where = PLAYER_NAME + "=?";
        String[] whereArgs = {name};

        this.openReadableDB();
        try {
            Cursor cursor = db.query(PLAYER_TABLE, null, where, whereArgs, null, null, null);
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            Player player = getPlayerFromCursor(cursor);
            if (cursor != null){
                cursor.close();
            }

            this.closeDB();
            return player;
        } catch (Exception e){
            Log.d("PlayerApp", "Exception " + e);
            return null;
        }

    }

    private Player getPlayerFromCursor(Cursor cursor) {
        if (cursor == null || cursor.getCount() == 0){
            return null;
        }
        else {
            try {
                Player player = new Player(
                        cursor.getInt(PLAYER_ID_COL),
                        cursor.getString(PLAYER_NAME_COL),
                        cursor.getInt(WINS_COL),
                        cursor.getInt(LOSSES_COL),
                        cursor.getInt(TIES_COL));
                return player;
            }
            catch(Exception e) {
                Log.d("PlayerApp", "Exception " + e);
                return null;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: try `db = this.openReadableDB();`. Plus checking cursor for null is useless. Plus you should check the result (true/false the latter if no move can be accomplished) of the `moveToFirst` else you might get index type exception.

Comment: db is an instance of the ScoreDB class that I use within the GameActivity. db = this.openReadable() within the ScoreDB class wouldn't be possible? Sorry I might be missing something in what you said.

Thanks for the advice on handling the exceptions too!

Comment: Edit your question to include all of the ScoreDB class. There is a good chance that **db** is null.

Comment: Added ScoreDB. There is other instances in the app where ScoreDB is working fine, where the user types in a username and it adds it as an entry to the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue appears to be that db is null when invoking the `returnPlayerByName` call.

Setting **`db`** as an instance of the `SCoreDB` class should resolve this issue. e.g. :-

```
    db = new ScoreDB(this); //<<<< ADDED note! assumes within an activity
    Player player1;
    player1 = db.returnPlayerByName(player_one);
    db.insertWinnerScore(player1);
```

Comment: Lifesaver! Thank you very much